# How do I open a port on my Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server to my Mac from which it runs?

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, port-forwarding, nmap

I’m running a virtual Ubuntu (14.04) box, using Vagrant, on my Mac Big Sur machine.  I would like to open port 1234 on my virtual machine to my Mac.  From the virtual machine, I can see these ports listening

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
[sudo] password for myuser: 
mysqld    1425   mysql   19u  IPv4  21538      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
sshd      1447    root    3u  IPv4  24616      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1447    root    4u  IPv6  24618      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
redis-ser 1449   redis    5u  IPv4  14782      0t0  TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)
master    1828    root   12u  IPv4  18076      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:25 (LISTEN)
master    1828    root   13u  IPv6  18077      0t0  TCP [::1]:25 (LISTEN)
ruby      7514  myuser    7u  IPv4  51854      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1234 (LISTEN)
node      7562  myuser   19u  IPv4  50542      0t0  TCP *:3500 (LISTEN)
```

However, I noticed when running nmap on my Mac, I’m not able to connect to port 1234

```
nmap -sT -p- 10.0.18.25
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-10-13 11:16 CDT
Nmap scan report for iad-3456273abcef.mlp.nq.smb.rcn.net (10.0.18.25)
Host is up (0.10s latency).
Not shown: 65531 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3306/tcp open  mysql
3500/tcp open  rtmp-port
6379/tcp open  redis

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1374.16 seconds
```

When I try and run a firewall rule update on my machine

```
$ sudo ufw allow 1234
WARN: uid is 0 but '/usr' is owned by 501
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

I’m still unable to reach port 1234 from my local machine to the virtual server.  What else do I need to do to open my virtual server’s port 1234?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That instance of *ruby* is listening on *port 1234* for connections *from 127.0.0.1 only*. So port forwarding won't change much unless you have it accept connections from your host machine.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that.  I'd like it to listen to all connections but not sure how to do that.  I start my instance using "rdebug-ide --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- bin/rails s", fwiw.

Comment: I wouldn't know. I know Linux but I'm not a ruby developer. Did you check the man page?

Comment: Starting the server with "rdebug-ide --port 1234 --dispatcher-port 26166 --host 0.0.0.0 - bin/rails s" corrected the error you pointed out.  Thx!